# Error when adding cordova plugin

Tags: cordova, plugins, addition

Hi i am updating my android program on cordova to newest version 6.1.1.

But when adding new plugin it throws error.

```
Error: Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/org.apache.cordova.splashscreen.
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Solved problem myself .

In new version we have to type as following

```
// npm hosted (new) id
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-splashscreen

// you may also install directly from this repo
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen.git
```

Answer (score 9):

I faced almost the same error while trying to install the device-motion for my project by typing the following:

`cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device-motion`

but this is not valid anymore, I typed instead

`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device-motion`

it works fine.